# How to use PowerShell in browser to GET-ADCOMPUTER

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have followed this [Guide](http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142) and made the page which can run powershell scripts in te browser and display the returned data on the page. The User enters a script the page calls powershell and then runs the input and displays the returned value. **An example script is below that does run and return a value**

```
Get-Process | Output-String
```

**I would like to run this command and have it return the Distinguished name of the server.**

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity (ServerName)
```

When ran I get no output could anyone elaborate to why this is or if there Is a wa I can execute this page from a browser?

Thank you

Comment: That seems like a lot of extra effort (and potential security issues) to go through when you could just use [PowerShell Web Access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831611\(v=ws.11\).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `PowerShell.Create()`, you can pass an `InitialSessionState` object containing the modules to import, in your case the `ActiveDirectory` module.

Instead of:

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
```

do

```
var initState = InitialSessionState.Create();
initState.ImportPSModule("ActiveDirectory");

var shell = PowerShell.Create(initState);
```

Dont forget a `using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;` statement.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use this to add the exchange snap in or apply profile to power shell session?

Comment: @DevilWAH See [this SF answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/698146/whats-the-supported-way-of-using-exchange-powershell-cmdlets-in-a-script/698220#698220)

Comment: Hi, Cheers, but I can not get this to work using powershell.create() although I have not tried passing "Connect-ExchangeServer -auto" as a paramator yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the `Distinguished name`:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity  (ServerName) -Properties * | select DistinguishedName
```